# Override django admin change form for a single model outside of my app?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm currently overriding `change_form.html` in my app by dropping it in:

```
myproject/myapp/templates/admin/change_form.html
```

That works fine but I really only want to override the change form for the `User` model, and nothing else.  It doesn't seem to work if I drop it in:

```
myproject/myapp/templates/admin/user/change_form.html
```

I'm guessing that's because the `User` model isn't from my app?

What's the cleanest way of overriding `change_list.html` for a specific model in some *other* app (namely, the `django.contrib.auth` app)?

---

Relevant snippets from `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'unicorn.context_processors.site_url',
                'unicorn.context_processors.consultant_data',
                'unicorn.context_processors.branding',
            ],
            'builtins': ['tracking.templatetags.tracking_extras'],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 4):

looks like you need to add your application name to the full path for the template, so it should be

`myproject/myapp/templates/admin/myapp/user/change_form.html`

Answer (score 1):

*settings.py*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': ...,
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Place `admin/auth/user/change_form.html` in project's `templates` directory.

- [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work... It works if I put it at `admin/auth/change_form.html` but not if I put it at `admin/auth/user/change_form.html`.  I've also added my value for `TEMPLATES` in my question.

Answer (score 0):

for Django 3.2+
first you need to create a similar admin template structure directory in your project which is:

```
- project_dir
- app
- templates/admin/ <---
- venv
```

and then copy the `change_form.html`
from `venv/lib/python[ver]/site-packages/dajngo/contrib/admin/templates/`
into: `/templates/admin/change_form.html`
wich is the template folder in your project
this assuming if you using virtualenv

and then set `settings.py` to:

```
import os
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        ...
```

and then you can modify the `/templates/admin/change_form.html` you already copy,
for example you only want show some text only for user model, you can do something like this:

look for line: `{% block field_sets %}` and below that put:

```
{% if opts.model_name == "user" %} Put Your Text Here {% endif %}
```

so it's looks like this:

```
{% block field_sets %}
{% if opts.model_name == "user" %} Put Your Text Here {% endif %}
```

You can replace the `user` with any model you want.

Answer (score -1):

**4 years late, but anyone looking for an answer--**
If you installed Grappelli package like me, your issue can be solved by going to `python/lib/site-packages/grappelli` and looking for the `change_form.html` there. This package overrides my custom template so I made changes to the grappelli file.